# Shared Entity in one to many database relationship

Tags: database, uml, relational-database, dry

I have a database I'm working on the design for. I have manufacturers and I have distributors on separate tables containing practically the same information with few exceptions. Both groups have one-many contacts that need to be connected to them. I created a contact table to hold contact information, one!

Do I need a second contact table? I'm trying to make this as DRY as possible. How would that look? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a case for the [party-role pattern](http://www.information-management.com/issues/20051101/1038793-1.html)?  `Manufacturer` and `Distributor` are roles played by Parties.  Contacts apply to Parties, not the role(s) they play.  So you'd have:

- a table named `Party`
- a table named `ContactMethod` (or similar)
- a 1:M relationship from Party to ContactMethod

which would resolve the need for two `Contact` tables.  How you model the roles side will depend on wider requirements.  The canonical model would have:

- a single supertype named `Role`
- a M:M relationship from Party to Role
- a subtype of Role for each specific role (Distributor and Manufacturer in your case).

(Note: as an aside, this also allows a Party to play both manufacturer and distributor roles - which may or may not be relevant).

There are 3 'standard' patterns for implementing a subtype hierarchy in relational tables:

1. table for entire hierarchy
2. table per leaf subtype
3. table per type

(1) would apply if you don't have any role-specific relationships.  (However I suspect that's unlikely; there's probably information related to Distributors that doesn't apply to Manufacturers and vice-versa).
(2) means multiple relationships from Party (i.e. one to each role subtype).

(3) avoids both above but means an extra join in navigating from Party to its role(s).

Like I say, choice depends on wider reqs.

hth.